# How to pass $data from CodeIgniter's controller to model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, undefined

Im trying to allow a user to edit their own details. Here is my code:
Controller:

```
public function myaccount() {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
        $this->load->model('myaccount_model');    
        $this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);
        $this->load->view('head');
        $this->load->view('myaccount', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');   
    } else {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Myaccount_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_details($data) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

It comes up with the error :Undefined variable $id on my account_model. The session is created at the controller as:

```
$data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
```

So how do i pass the data from the controller, to the model so i can query the database and select the user that matches the session id? Thanks

Comment: You should really start with the basics of functions and methods: `http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php`

Comment: Ragnar's answer is good. Notice you never define $id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no variable at your model $id inside get details function.
try to change your  getdetails function like this

```
public function get_details($data)
{
  $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $data['id']));
  return $query->row_array();

}
```

Or you can pass only id instead of $data like this from your controller

```
$this->myaccount_model->get_details($session_data['id']);
```

Now you can change your model like this

```
public function get_details($id)
{
  $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
  return $query->row_array();

}
```

Comment: Thanks :) How would i echo out the username and email in the view? i can't use "foreach ($id->result() as $row)" because id isn't set to anything?

Comment: You are returning row_array so it will return only one result as array. so you cannot use foreach

Comment: to pass result inside view write this way `$data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);` now you will get it as $result inside your view.for email you can `echo $result['email']`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$data['id']` because you are setting the value in your controller

```
public function get_details($data)
{
   $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $data['id']));
   return $query->row_array();    
}
```

In order to echo out user data in your view I think you can do something like this:

```
$userData = $this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);
$this->load->view('myaccount', $userData);
```

Comment: How would i echo out the username and email in the view? i can't use "foreach ($id->result() as $row)" because id isn't set to anything?